# Is Facebook Audience Network Mobile Web not available?

Tags: facebook, mobile-website, ads, facebook-audience-network

What does it mean by Closed Beta?
[image: Audience Network Mobile web closed beta]

https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/overview

Is this service available to a restricted group?
How can one participate in this closed beta project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service is not available to the public. As of April 2017 the [page for web integration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/implementing-mobile) still displays a notice stating that mobile web integration is available only to certain publishers.

[This article gives a good rundown](https://adexchanger.com/platforms/in-test-with-10-publishers-facebook-extends-audience-network-to-mobile-web-placements/) on why they're moving slowly into the web-space, and implies that to become a part of the closed beta you'll need to be a big fish i.e. Facebook will contact you if you're to be included.